# Timeout expired SQL Execution error

Tags: sql-server

SQL Execution error!

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

How to solve the timeout expired issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change Connection string to increase time out:

```
Data Source=YourDBServer;Initial Catalog=YourDB;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;
Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Connect Timeout=60;
```

Hope this helps you out <3

Answer (score 0):

In properties of the instance you can leave it with value 0, which will allow the maximum possible.

To do this right-click on the sql instance and then properties, then connections.

Change the timeout for remote connection.